# How to set PipeSecurity of NamedPipeServerStream in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, named-pipes, .net-standard-2.0

I'm porting a library from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Standard 2.0. In Framework, the `NamedPipeServerStream` constructor could take a `PipeSecurity` parameter, but that isn't an option in Core. How do you set the security of a `NamedPipeServerStream` in Core?

Answer (score 16):

Net 6.0 has introduced [NamedPipeServerStreamAcl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstreamacl).

You can use the [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstreamacl.create) method to create the stream with PipeSecurity...

```csharp
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

if (!System.OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Windows only");

SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(
    WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(securityIdentifier,
    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance,
    AccessControlType.Allow));

NamedPipeServerStream stream = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create(
    "SecurityTestPipe", PipeDirection.InOut,
    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
    PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 0, 0, pipeSecurity);
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it's a known issue
[System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl package does not work #26869](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26869). There's a workaround mentioned in the last post suggesting usage of [NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion/) nuget package which will expose `NamedPipeServerStreamConstructors.New(...)` which should mirror behavior of all the full .NET Framework constructors.

Follows a code sample from the nuget's [github](https://github.com/HavenDV/H.Pipes/tree/master/NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion)

```
using System.IO.Pipes;

var pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

using var serverStream = NamedPipeServerStreamConstructors.New(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 0, 0, pipeSecurity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for .NET 8:

```
var stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 0, 0);

stream.SetAccessControl(pipeSecurity);
```