# I'm making a synapse x custom ui and I keep on getting this error

Tags: c#, winforms, roblox

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513   Message=Method
> not found: 'Void
> System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor(System.String,
> System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection, Int32,
> System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode, System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions,
> Int32, Int32, System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity)'.   Source=sxlib
> StackTrace:    at sxlib.Specialized.SxLibBase..()    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Getting this from sxlib and I don't know why it's happening, because it looks like an error with SxLib

Here is  code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using sxlib;
using sxlib.Specialized;
using sxlib.Internal;
using System.IO.Pipes;   

namespace synsense
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool Attached;
        public bool Loaded;
        public static string Direct = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Functions.Lib = SxLib.InitializeWinForms(this, Direct);
            Functions.Lib.Load();
            Functions.Lib.LoadEvent += SynLoadEvent;
        }

        private void SynLoadEvent(SxLibBase.SynLoadEvents Event, object Param)
        {
            status.Text = Event.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969943/how-to-set-pipesecurity-of-namedpipeserverstream-in-net-core might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix

Change to .NET Framework 4.7.2 if you have the same issue.

You will need to make a new project and make sure its a .NET Framework Forms App.